# Creating a distinct list of names with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will try and keep this as concise and easy to understand as possible. I have a dataset which includes a large number of names, some are distinct, however some are not and all names have a corresponding reference number. Where the names are not distinct, I want to create a query that will display a distinct list all of names in that table, and have seperate columns that list listing the reference numbers of the names in the original dataset. Is this at all possible using SQL? I was thinking a PIVOT clause might be required, but not sure that would be appropriate

Like below;

**Current Dataset**

| FullName | Reference |
| --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | T1234567 |
| Joe Bloggs | T3456789 |
| John Smith | T1234568 |
| Sarah Edwards | T1234567 |
| Karen Culford | T0999221 |
| Sarah Edwards | T0239222 |
| Joe Bloggs | T2045292 |

**Desired Outcome**

| FullName | Reference1 | Reference2 | Reference3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | T1234567 | T3456789 | T2045292 |
| John Smith | T1234568 | NULL | NULL |
| Sarah Edwards | T1234567 | T0239222 | NULL |
| Karen Culford | T0999221 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some products have PIVOT, which can be useful here.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server - thanks

Comment: Then PIVOT is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to have any suggestions on code for this?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not a SQL Server guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of pivot columns is unknown, you'd need dynamic sql (which has both [pros and cons](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)). Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351133/8895292) as a base, first build a comma separated list of column names *"Reference1,Reference2,...."*.

**SQL Server 2017+**

```
DECLARE @colList AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


; WITH colsByName AS (
   -- count how many columns per fullName
   SELECT FullName
        , Reference
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY Fullname ORDER BY Reference) AS ColNum
   FROM   YourTable       
)
, uniqueColumns AS
(
    -- get unique column numbers
    SELECT DISTINCT ColNum
    FROM   colsByName
)
-- build comma separated list of names
SELECT @colList = STRING_AGG('Reference'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColNum), ',')
FROM   uniqueColumns
;
```

*Note, for SQL Server 2016 use STUFF instead of [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)*

```
...
-- build comma separated list of names
SELECT @colList = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + 'Reference'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColNum)
            FROM  uniqueColumns
            ORDER BY ColNum
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        ,1,1,'') 
;
```

Then use it to build a dynamic PIVOT statement:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT FullName, ' + @colList + ' 
              FROM (
                     SELECT FullName
                             , Reference
                             , ''Reference''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY Fullname ORDER BY Reference)) AS ColNum
                     FROM   YourTable
              ) x
              PIVOT
              (
                  MAX(Reference)
                  FOR ColNum IN (' + @colList + ')
            ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

See also

- [SQL Server 2017+ Example  - db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72a757133e5b17499db54e8de1a0c97f)
- [SQL Server 2016 Example - db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=03ae46d14900d3e5a761880ae41ce8a5)

**Results**

| FullName | Reference1 | Reference2 | Reference3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | 3456789 | T1234567 | T2045292 |
| John Hart |  |  |  |
| John Smith | T1234568 |  |  |
| Karen Culford | T0999221 |  |  |
| Sarah Edwards | T0239222 | T1234567 |  |

Comment: Thanks for the above example - looks great, however I am running SQL Server 2016 so STRING_AGG does not apply, is there any chance the query above could be amended  using STUFF?

Comment: @pdwebb23 - Sure, see updated answer and fiddles

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick!

Comment: @SOS I think in your string aggregation, you create one comma to much. In your 2017 plus version you need to drop it with left(length of colllist -1). In your 2016 and below version you need to use right(length of collist - 1)